# Application Virtualization vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, streaming, virtualization

In our organization, we have an application which is needed to be accessed by our boss. We update this application everyday and our boss requested to be able to access this update everyday. The application is very large, over 8GB in size, so it is deployed to a private computer, where every update we perform, will update the files on that computer. Due to the huge file and regular updates, we can't copy the application to our boss's PC everyday for him to check updates, which is where the problem comes in.

**OUR GOAL**
We want our boss to be able to access this application from his computer over the network (private network) without actually installing the application on his computer.

**WHAT WE HAVE TRIED**
At first we looked at using a [VNC program](https://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html), this actually works but the problem is whenever our boss is checking through the application, we cannot use the PC again until he is done checking. He spent hours checking and we cannot interrupt him, otherwise, we get **fired**. This hours of checking won't allow us to continue our work which makes us always receive query of not meeting our daily target and boss doesn't want excuse other than **get the job done**

Next, we thought about using the [VNC program](https://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html) to execute ONLY the application. I did a lot of google search to see how to achieve this, but to no avail. During my finding, i came across [this vnc application](http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/virtual_display_manager.pl) which is specifically built to share single window application over a VNC. After attempting to use it, it actually worked, but the problem we face in the previous attempt is still what we face in this attempt, which is, when boss is checking, we can't use the PC until he is done checking. This is because mouse and keyboard events are sent to this PC during operation, which makes the PC useless for us not until boss is done.

Now, this raises another question:

Is it possible to share an application over VNC without sending keyboard and mouse events to the PC where the application is installed?

After series of googling, i came across the term "Application Virtualization". After reading a lot of wikipedia pages and lots of googling, i came across some virtualization software which i have tried:

[Cameyo](https://cameyo.com/) requested to upload application to their server and it can be accessed from any device via web browser, which is not what we need. The application is on a PC, not on a server (we don't want it on the internet).

[Ceedo](https://www.ceedo.com/) runs application in a separate container like sandboxie but still on the same local PC, which is not what we want. We want it accessed over a network (private network).

[Citrix XenApp](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/) and [Microsoft App-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/app-v/appv-getting-started) works the same way, they require to first, open their installer monitor software and then install your own application, and after installation, their monitor software would have monitored the install location of your own application and creates an executable for you to deploy on the remote PC. This cannot work in our case because: (1) We update everyday, and (2) the application is already installed.

After weeks of googling and getting no result, it looks like what we want to achieve is impossible. Now, when i was about to give up, i came across [this video](https://streamable.com/w5z1g) which does EXACTLY what we want to achieve. This video gives me hope that what i want to achieve is actually possible.

Now, i took my time to carefully watch the video, first, i got the name of the software and googled, and i discover its a Trojan, so i don't bother to search for the download link. But still interested in the video. After carefully watching the video, i noticed some things

1. The application is accessed using a [VNC software](https://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html)
2. I noticed the keyboard and mouse event sent by the VNC software is NOT sent to the computer where the software is actually installed. Probably sent to a server somewhere
3. At 2:42 minutes of the video, i noticed that, when the real application was closed (terminated), the application is still open inside the VNC which makes me strongly believe that probably the [application is streamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_streaming) to another server where the VNC connects to.

After watching the video, i tried to contact the developer of the [VNC Software](https://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html) used in that video to no avail.

Now, i don't know what to do again, please **how can i access installed application from a computer where it is not installed over a network (private network)?**

Comment: Rather long winded ! why don't you just try using remote desktop with multiple concurrent sessions using something like an RDP Wrapper.

Comment: Virtualization may not be your best approach. It sounds like you need to decouple things a bit. Have a look at [Squirrel](https://github.com/squirrel/squirrel.windows) for building automatic self-updating applications. That said, what exactly comprises your 8GB+ updates? (That's pretty big for an update!) Is it data? Put it in a centrally-located database. Is it assemblies? Build in self-updating. What is it that's so big in the thing?

Comment: Thank you sir @InteXX i will check it out and get back to you later. 
BASit Thanks for the wonderful comment, we have already tried multi-session RDP, when the application opens, it doesn't load all the work that has been done on it, it opens "freshly" like a newly installed application, because all activities are saved on current user profile. Since multi-session RDP uses another user profile.